# asks for password when trying to format unencrypted HDD

Tags: permissions

I have a clean install of Ubuntu on an SSD which works fine , and no passwords activated in BIOS , or Ubuntu boot.

I have added a formatted HDD but Ubuntu apparently cant see it , if i open the "Discs app" i can see the drive but when  i try to format it in any mode it asks me for a password.

How do i get around that so i can format it (to work with windows and Linux) and so the OS can see and provide access ?

The discs both show in the BIOS boot order but i cant format and cant use the HDD  ?

I even put that HDD on a windows PC and formatted it easily without being asked for a password , but on the Ubuntu system its not behaving  ??

Comment: A clean install of Ubuntu requires the creation of an admin account, with a password.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by reinstalling Ubuntu.

If anyone had an answer it wont hurt to share in case someone else gets the same issue

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that you need extended user rights to format the hard drive. If you are the main user of the system, you only have to enter your user password there. This behavior of Ubuntu is supposed to protect you (also as the main user) from hasty, deeply intrusive actions. So if you are asked for your own password there, then go into yourself, fill in the password and then press Return.